# Run the standard supertest example

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, supertest

Hi I am trying to run a standard example from the supertest package.

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'john' });
});

request(app)
  .get('/user')
  .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  .expect('Content-Length', '15')
  .expect(200)
  .end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

It crashes with an Operation timed out error:

```
Error: ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out
    at Test.assert (G:\Projects\Nodejs\testJest\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:200:18)
    at Server.localAssert (G:\Projects\Nodejs\testJest\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:166:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:481:28)
    at Server.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at emitCloseNT (net.js:1661:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! testjest@1.0.0 start: `node main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the testjest@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dmitriy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-02T09_36_09_387Z-debug.log
```

what am I doing wrong?

I using node v14.17.1, npm v6.14.13, supertest v6.1.4, express v4.17.1 and superagent v6.1.0.

Comment: That's not actually in a test, you need `it`/`test` and https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous.

Comment: Is it always reproducible? Could you show the whole package.json?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually it should work as is, that's the example taken directly from supertest docpage. But yes, most often it's used within tests.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. It works fine for me